# Can't install google plugin for eclipse 3.7

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:

```
(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.core_2.3.3.r37v201107211953.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.core_2.3.3.r37v201107211953.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.maven_2.3.3.r37v201107211953.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.core_2.3.3.r37v201107211953.jar.
Read timed out
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've solved it by downloading the repository from a hidden link:

http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/core/3.7/zips/gpe-e37-latest-updatesite.zip

and updating from there

See the [documentation on Google's website](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip).

Comment: I tried multiple times to get this installed and this was the only solution that worked!  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue if you're behind a firewall and have not configured Eclipse to go around it. The link in the accepted answer did not work for me... found ones that did work though.

http://dl.google.com/dl/eclipse/inst/codepro/latest/codeproanalytix_v7.1.0_updatesite_for_eclipse3.7.zip

http://dl.google.com/dl/eclipse/inst/codepro/latest/codeproanalytix_v7.1.0_updatesite_for_eclipse3.6.zip

http://dl.google.com/dl/eclipse/inst/codepro/latest/codeproanalytix_v7.1.0_updatesite_for_eclipse3.5.zip

http://dl.google.com/dl/eclipse/inst/codepro/latest/codeproanalytix_v7.1.0_updatesite_for_eclipse3.4.zip